# How can I revert back to a previously working VM Instance On Google Cloud?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I recently edited the VM Instance by adding more processing power to it. It now appears that the disk image source cannot be found.

It throws this error: The resource "bitnami-lampstack-7-1-24-0-linux-debian-9-x86-64" was not found

https://snipboard.io/CcNG7F.jpg

Comment: More details are required.

Comment: Without snapshot or backup images, revert back to stable state is not possible.

Comment: Mahboob, I have backup images, how do I go about it?

Comment: @Kevin, create a new instance from the image then. While creating the new vm change the processing power as per your requirement.